# Overriding private methods

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, private, overriding

My java book has the following practice question:

```
public class Person(){...}

public class Teacher extends Person{...}
```

And it asks which of the following are true statements:

1: Teacher inherits the constructors of `Person`.

2: Teacher can add new methods and private instance variables.

3: Teacher can override existing private methods of `Person`.

The book says 2 and 3 are true. I said only 2 is true.

I have read that subclasses do indeed inherit private methods and member fields yet they cannot be directly accessed. So my question is how would one override existing private methods if they cannot be directly accessed? And why would one want to override private methods if they were probably made private for a good reason?

Comment: @Scott Barron's AP Computer Science A 6th Edition

Comment: They might have meant protected? Or it's just a mistake. When you have a lot of information, a few mistakes are bound to slip through.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> 3: Teacher can override existing private methods of Person.

That's wrong.

Private methods/fields of super class are not visible/inherited to sub classes. So, You can't override them.

Try it with an example

Comment: Very much so. Just type this example out and see what happens when you try to compile.

Comment: @SimionMita see my post i dont think the book is wrong, perhaps wrong choice of words only

Answer (score 2):

methods are inherited only if they are `public` or `protected` or has no access modifier. `private` cannot be inherited. I think what the book meant `Teacher` can 'override' private method of `Person` via creating a similar method name with broader or similar access modifier, since Teacher does not see the method. This is called Method Shadowing.  **it's either the book chose the wrong word using override instead of shadowing, or gave wrong answer.**

Example:

```
public class Person(){
  private void sayHello(){...}    
}

public class Teacher extends Person{
   public void sayHello(){...}
}
```

Comment: I am not sure if this would really count as overriding though. Would it?

Comment: This is not called overriding.

Comment: nope this is method shadowing, either the book choose the wrong word using override instead of shadowing, or gave wrong answer.

Comment: Since thus far we haven't spoke of "shadowing" I'll accept that the book is wrong. I'll check with my teacher though.

Comment: Just annotate the method in `Teacher` with [`@Override`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Override.html) and see what the compiler has to say?

Comment: "Method does not override method from its superclass." Which makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

JLS [§8.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.2)

> Members of a class that are declared private are not inherited by subclasses of that class.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, a subclass cannot override the private methods of an inherited class. This is specifically the purpose of the protected keyword. It is for functions and data members that are supposed to be private to other objects, but still accessible to subclasses. If the private functions could be accessed by the sub class, there would be no purpose for the protected keyword then.